# Why "Inspect in IDEA" not working in Intellij 13

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using InteliJ 13 and Live Edit for HTML works great, but, why when I right click somewhere in chrome browser on an HTML element and select from context menu "Inspect in IDEA" nothing happens?

it should open my HTML with that element in IntelliJ no? bug?

this is the menu I am talking about:
[image]

Answer (score 6):

This isn't supposed to do what you think it does.

It gives you a way of entering the debugging mode for a page in IntelliJ idea.

To see what I mean, start debugging a page in Chrome the normal way via **Run** -> **Debug mypage.html** in IDEA. Then, in chrome, click this button on the top ribbon to cancel the debugging:

[image]

You may now resume the debugging, by using **Inspect in IDEA** on the same page. This is all it may be used for, and, unfortunately, it does not offer anything as comprehensive as Inspect Element in chrome, which is probably what you were expecting.